# curl: no URL specified for restful api

Tags: bash, rest, curl

I have been asked to call a restful api via Unix environment. Is there a bug in my command so i got blow issue?

I have tried looking at the curl --help  but the thing that I could find that might help would be the way to pass in param key-pair. Could it be possible to give me an example how to debug such api calling?

```
$ curl -d param1=xxx&param2=yyy -X POST https://restful_api_path/lifecycle/v1/resource_node
[1]     10276
[2]     10277
-ksh: -X: not found [No such file or directory]
[2] +  Done                    curl -d param1=xxx&param2=yyy -X POST https://restful_api_path/lifecycle/v1/resource_node
$ curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Cheers

Comment: Enclose your params in quotes - `curl -d 'param1=xxx&param2=yyy' `

Comment: Didn’t you ever wonder what the lines `[1]     10276` and `[2]     10277` might signify?

Answer (score 15):

You need to enclose your params in single or double quotes. e.g.

```
curl -d 'param1=xxx&param2=yyy' -X POST https://restful_api_path/lifecycle/v1/resource_node
```

This is because the `&` operator in BASH is used to signify that the command should continue to run the in background, hence it must be quoted or escaped if you want a literal ampersand.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to add double quotes to quote arguments:

```
curl -d "param1=xxx&param2=yyy" -X POST https://restfulurl/lifecycle/v1/resourcenode
```

P.S.
On Windows you need to use double quotes, not single quotes. But in Unix, it supports both double and single quotes to quote arguments.
So below cmd are fine also:

```
curl -d 'param1=xxx&param2=yyy' -X POST https://restfulurl/lifecycle/v1/resourcenode
```

Answer (score -3):

envsubst < $WORKDIR/migrate-storage/incident.json | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" $FUNCTION_URL -d @-

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked.